# How to pass the data to the tableview after getting URL on the terminal? Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift5

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class NetworkingService {
    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    private init() {}

    func getPeople(completion: () -> Void) {
        AF.request(API.SpaceX.upcomingLaunches.url()).responseJSON{ (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):
                print(value)
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have got the JSON data from the api https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/upcoming in my terminal . Now I want to decode the data using swiftyJSON or Alamofire & show it on my tableview cell but I am unable to do. I want to use codable alamofire & I have written those codes in the other file given below

```
    import Foundation

struct Mission: Codable {

    let flight_number: Int
    let mission_name: String
    let launch_date_utc: String
    let launch_date_local: String

    struct Rocket: Codable {
        let rocket_id: String
        let rocket_name: String
        let rocket_type: String
        let first_stage: FirstStage
        let second_stage: SecondStage
    }

    struct FirstStage: Codable {
        let cores: [Core]
    }

    struct Core: Codable {
        let core_serial: String?
        let flight: Int?
        let reused: Bool?
    }

    struct SecondStage: Codable {
        let payloads: [Payload]
    }

    struct Payload: Codable {
        let payload_id: String
        let reused: Bool?
        let customers: [String]
        let payload_type: String?
    }

    struct LaunchSite: Codable {
        let site_id: String
        let site_name: String
        let site_name_long: String
    }

    struct Links: Codable {
        let mission_patch: String?
        let presskit: String?
        let article_link: String?
        let video_link: String?
        let reddit_campaign: String?
    }

    let rocket: Rocket
    let launch_site: LaunchSite
    let links: Links
}
```

Here above is my codeable data. I want to provide all such details in my `Tableview cell`. Can you please help me in rewritting the code either by swiftyJSON or alamofire? :)

```
import Foundation
struct API {
    enum SpaceX {
        case allLaunches
        case pastLaunches
        case upcomingLaunches
        case latestLaunch
        case nextLAunch

        func url() -> String {
            switch self {
            case .allLaunches:
                return "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches"

            case .pastLaunches:
                return "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/past"

            case .upcomingLaunches:
                return "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/upcoming"


            case .latestLaunch:
                return "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/latest"

            case .nextLAunch:
                return "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/next"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

above is the api func I made.

Comment: If you are using `Codable` structs then you don't need SwiftyJson. You can just use a json decoder with your data from the api request.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the info but how to write the json decoder? I have seen the Alamofire documentaion but I am facing some confusions since I have learned new. Can you please help me in writing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here, First you need to convert your data to custom object using **JSONDecoder**. For this you need to use *Codable* like you already do. Here also you can use **responseData** instead of **responseJSON**, than it's success case directly get data.

```
func getPeople(completion: () -> Void) {
    AF.request(API.SpaceX.upcomingLaunches.url()).responseJSON{ (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case let .success(value):
            print(value)
            if let data = response.data {
                // Convert to Object
                do {
                    let responseDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Mission].self, from: data)
                    print(responseDecoded.count)
                } catch let error {
                    // Parser error
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's been helpful.

Comment: Here response is complicated that contain object inside array. `Codable` is more complicated to use here, you need to take care of all cases. Here you can use your own custom **initializer** that parse JSON(Dictionary) to object.

Comment: Now what to do next? Since I want to pass the info to tableview cell. What shall i do next?

Comment: Regarding codable you said, that it's difficult to use. Ok fine but what do next?

Comment: @Eliza You must use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` to display cell. In your cell class create method like `setDetails(_ mission: Mission)`. Still have an issue then update your question with cell class.